# Core Animation Transition with Swift

Tags: swift, core-animation, ios8

Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html) have this sample:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
...
```

But when I did it in Swift:

```
    let transition = CATransition.animation()
```

I got an error "animation()' is unavailable: use object construction 'CAAnimation()'" - is this deprecated or? If yes, what's the new way of doing transition?

Comment: read the error again, does it tell you anything might help?

Comment: That's what I did, but there is no CAAnimation() in CATransition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Objective-C `[CAAnimation animation]` is a convenience method for:

```
[[[CAAnimation alloc] init] autorelease]
```

`CATransition` inherits `CAAnimation` and therefore inherits the convenience constructor.

In Swift, this kind of initialization is gone, and you can create the `CATransition` object using the default constructor.

Try `let transition = CATransition()`

Answer (score 0):

CATransition.animation() use to be used to create a new instance of CAAnimation. As you said, this appears to be deprecated now. CAAnimation is not a function/property defined in CATransition, it's a separate class altogether (this is implied by the 'CA' prefix). Therefore, it can be initialized using the following code:

```
CAAnimation()
```

or

```
CAAnimation(coder: aCoder)
```

instead of

```
CATransition.animation()
```

Comment: Once changed to CAAnimation(), seems that all the rest need to change. It seems that the answer below is the correct replacement.

Comment: `CAAnimation()` is the constructor for a CAAnimation object, which is the superclass of CATransition. To get an instance of a CATransition, you use its constructor, `CATransition()`.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood and thought you were attempting to create an instance of CAAnimation not CATransition.